# django rest framework delete item based on a field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using a router & ReadOnlyModelViewset, and try to create an API service that allows deleting of an item based on only specific field in the item, such as:
    http://localhost/delete_post?author="abc"

I guess urls.py and views.py need changes, what's the right way to override routers and viewModels to achieve this?

**models.py**

```
class post(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

**views.py**

```
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bulk delete. I would suggest to implementing it via filtering and custom list route:

```python
import django_filters
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import list_route


class PostFilterSet(django_filter.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = (
            'author',
        )

class PostViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    filter_backends = (
        filters.DjangoFilterBackend,
    )
    filter_class = PostFilterSet

    @list_route(methods=['post'])
    def delete_post(self, request, *arg, **kwarg):
        # retrieve the selected items
        qs = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        # delete the selected item
        qs.delete()
        # return deleted
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Now in your router, you have a new route available named /delete_post where if you post with a query param author=(name of the author without quotes) it will delete all the posts satisfying the filter.